# expectation of a poisson variable

Tags: statistics, poisson-distribution, expected-value

Assume I have products available to buy and I get 4 ($\lambda = 4$) customers (poisson distributed) wanting to buy some of them everyday for $10 each.

The poisson distribution is

$$
P(X = k) = \frac{\lambda^k e^{-\lambda}}{k!}
$$

I know that the expectation of a poisson distribution is the $\lambda$, so then is my expected profit going to be $40 everyday or do I have to do something else in order to calculate the expectation of profit?

Comment: Yes. To be clear, you get an *average* of $4$ customers per day. If $N$ is the number of customers then ignoring all costs your profit is $aN$, where $a=\$10$ the selling price, the expected profit of which is $\mathbb{E}(aN)=a\mathbb{E}(N)=a\lambda$.

Answer (score 0):

If you want more detailed solution:

$E[\text{profit}] = \sum^{\infty}_{k = 0} 10 \cdot k \cdot \frac{\lambda ^ k e^{-\lambda}}{k!} = 10 \cdot \sum^{\infty}_{k = 0}\frac{\lambda ^ k e^{-\lambda}}{k!} = 10 \cdot \lambda = 40.$

As to how $ \sum^{\infty}_{k = 0}\frac{\lambda ^ k e^{-\lambda}}{k!} =   \lambda$, you can find the proof [here](https://llc.stat.purdue.edu/2014/41600/notes/prob1804.pdf).

Hope it helped!